# How to Shutdown spring boot application gracefully

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Spring boot application server up and serves requests. After few days/hours I would like to shutdown spring application/process gracefully by sending an event or calling an endpoint through trusted sources, but I don't like to send kill signal to process.

Comment: Hi, What about spring boot actuator shut down api.?

Comment: @Sreyas Tried spring boot actuator API, its not shutting down spring embedded tomcat, tomcat is up and running

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Spring Boot Actuator.  Add the following dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Configure in your `application.properties`:

```
management.server.port: 8081
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: *
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default: true
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled: true
#management.security.enabled: false
```

And use the "shutdown" endpoint to shutdown:

```sh
$ curl -X POST localhost:8081/actuator/shutdown
```

Comment: Got following response  
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
Nov 23, 2020 10:04:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Nov 23, 2020 10:04:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9510"]
Nov 23, 2020 10:04:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9510"] but still tomcat server is up and running